# How to create a rating based off social scores

Tags: algorithm, rating

I have a thousand recipes each having a tweet and facebook like counts. What i want to do is to create an overall rating out of 100 based off these two scores (and perhaps other social network counts too).

Assuming both facebook and twitter are equally weighted, how can i go about this.

one way to do this for any given network would be somethign like this

this_recipes_facebook_count / max_facebook_count_in_db * 100.0

and average it with the twitter result.

However what happens if there is a recipe with a freakish high score? It unfairly punishes other recipes with lower yet still relatively high scores.

I feel i need to take standard deviation into acccount, perhaps some dampening function...but its been 14 years since i took stats in highschool.

Can anyone help? Id prefer simple over complex as it is only recipe ratings after all.

Comment: Correlating popularity with rating confuses me - what would a 100% rating actually mean? That a recipe is 100% popular? And since not all recipes that are voted on in FB and TW are included, would not any comparison/statistical analysis be skewed? Not to mention that different socially-connected-groups may be voting on different recipes on FB and TW.

Comment: I admit that the number of tweets or likes (popularity) doesnt necessarily equate to a rating. But those are the only indicators i have. Instead of bombarding the user with multiple social scores I just want to wrap it up in one figure ala a rating or score. And yes this would result in great recipes which are not "Social" being unfairly demoted - that's fine by me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant when you said "However what happens if there is a recipe with a freakish high score? It unfairly punishes other recipes with lower yet still relatively high scores." What is considered a "relatively high score?" If you're trying to rank the 1000 recipes then I don't think the score difference really matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of linearly increasing the popularity count you might do something like this: (1-p^x)

Where p is a pre-selected value (say 0.99) and x is the number of mentions.

Initially increase in mentions is going to speed up the score a lot. But after sometime the effect becomes smaller and smaller.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for! brilliant. I found using 0.993 for facebook and 0.99 for twitter creates just the results i was looking for. Thank you.